# multiple category-UIDs for selection (category-tree)?

Tags: categories, typoscript, typo3-9.x, tx-news

is it possible to specify multiple entry points in the category tree for example tx_news-dataset? Or can it only be restricted by one uid? (rootUid)

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.categories.config.treeConfig.rootUid = 25
```

Maybe there is another solution like PAGE_TSCONFIG_IDLIST for categories?
Or can you e.g. limit the PID for the category-records so that only those from a special folder are displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For own data records it should work with the specification of PAGE_TSCONFIG_IDLIST and the UIDs of the folder with category data records.

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.categories.PAGE_TSCONFIG_IDLIST = 89,99
```

tx_news has an extension setting in which you have to specify how the categories should behave, in my case Category restriction -> Page TS-Config
default is: No restriction